# jQuery conflict between 1.4.2 and 1.7.2 file

Tags: jquery

i have integrated draggableQuiz in php file and this jQuery plugin works with jQuery 1.4.2 and i have already integrated jQuery UI dialog box in same file which works with jQuery 1.7.2 file,

Before integration of draggableQuiz plugin, UI dialog working fine but now its not working,

anyone have solution for same pls let me know,

Thanks in advance,
Manish

Comment: Remove the `jQuery 1.4.2` ..it will work fine

Comment: @ubercooluk Have you used jQuery v1.7.2 with the draggableQuiz plugin. How can you be sure `it will work fine`? The [_draggableQuiz_](https://github.com/mpezzi/jquery.ui.draggable.quiz) plugin I could find hasn't been updated in 2 years so it might not work with newer jQuery

Comment: You can try..i cant do that for you

Answer (score 2):

You should have only one jquery version file on a webpage.

So remove reference for `jQuery 1.4.2`, and work with `jQuery 1.7.2` or latest.

If you find any issue when working with jQuery 1.7.2, update your other jquery plugin files also which support this version.

Answer (score 0):

You should use jquery.min.js from google library.

[Download jquery min](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js)